# How do I make a comboxbox event able to calculate fields in a datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, calculated-columns

How do I make a comboxbox event able to calculate fields in a datagridview in vb.net?.

previously I used bunifuDataGridView1_CellEndEdit for column calculations in datagridview but now I use ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted but I don't know how to do column calculations in datagridview so please solution.

Thanks

[image: DATAGRIDVIEW TOTAL]

```
 Private Sub bunifuDataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles bunifuDataGridView1.CellEndEdit
            'calcutalte
            If e.ColumnIndex = 2 OrElse e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
                Dim row = bunifuDataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
                row.Cells(4).Value = Double.Parse(row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()) * Double.Parse(row.Cells(3).Value.ToString())
                Calculate()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub Calculate()
            Dim tot As Double = 0
            Dim cash As Double = Double.Parse(txtCash.Text)
            For Each item As DataGridViewRow In bunifuDataGridView1.Rows
                tot += Double.Parse(item.Cells(4).Value.ToString())
            Next item

            lblTotal.Text = tot.ToString("N2")


            lblChange.Text = (cash - tot).ToString("N2")
        End Sub
       Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
            fillDataGridView1()


        End Sub
Private Sub fillDataGridView1()
            Try
                Dim query As String = "SELECT NOD,ITM,CIU,QTY FROM RPD WHERE QTY > 0 AND PNM=@PNM"
                'Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM GSDTS WHERE QTY > 0"
                Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                    Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
                        Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                            da.Fill(dt)
                            da.Dispose()
                            source1.DataSource = dt
                            Me.bunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = source1
                      dt.Columns("Total").Expression = "[CIU]*[QTY]"          Me.bunifuDataGridView1.Refresh()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
  Private Sub PopulateComboBox()
            Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM RPD "
            Try
                Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                    Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
                        'Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)

                        'Insert the Default Item to DataTable.
                        Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

                        row(0) = ""

                        dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)

                        'Assign DataTable as DataSource.
                        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
                        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "PNM"
                        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "PNM"
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch myerror As OleDbException
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
            Finally

            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: What is `ComboBox1` meant to select? What is the DataSource of your DataGridView? (add the details to the body of your question) -- Those USB cables are not cheap at all!

Comment: @Jimi , `What is ComboBox1 meant to select?` `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PNM", ComboBox1.SelectedValue)` . i have updated the code in the post. Thank you for your reply

Comment: You should add an [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) to the `Total` Column, then perform the other calculations in, e.g., `DataBindingComplete`, using the Rows of the DataTable instead of the Rows of the DGV -- BTW, your Column should already contain `Double` value, so just cast to `Double` instead of parsing the actual value converted to string. Also, since those values represent currency, use `Decimal` instead of `Double`

Comment: @Jimi , `Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()  sda.Fill(dt)  Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()  dt.Columns("Total").Expression = "[Price]*[Quantity]" row(0) = ""  dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0) ComboBox1.DataSource = dt` I use combobox population but I have an error  `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Why are you adding an empty DataRow to the DataTable? Also, that's meant to work with the DataGridView -- You haven't explained what this ComboBox is meant to do, what its DataSource is and what the relation with the data source of the DataGridView is

Comment: @Jimi , thank you reply from you , sorry I was late replying, I use combobox population , I have also updated the code in the post `PopulateComboBox()`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this: `dt.Columns("Total").Expression = "[Price]*[Quantity]"` in the data source of the ComboBox. As already mentioned, this applies to the data source of the DataGridView

Comment: @Jimi , `source1.DataSource = dt Me.bunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = source1 dt.Columns("Total").Expression = "[Price]*[Quantity]"`  If I use it in datasource datagridview like this code at the time I select it in combobox it doesn't show anything in datagridview

Comment: @Jimi , I have also updated the code in this post

Comment: In your source of data, you don't have any `Total`, `Price`, or `Quantity` Columns. Your Columns are named `NOD`, `ITM`, `QTY` etc. Don't confuse the label applied to a Column in a DataGridView with its actual name

Comment: @Jimi , Thank you for your reply. `Quantity with property name QTY and Price with property name CIU ` And I made my code like this `dt.Columns("Total").Expression = "[CIU]*[QTY]"` and also I have done an update in the post code and in the total column still does not appear value.

Comment: Your DataTable doesn't have a Column named `Total` -- Remove empty `catch` blocks and don't use them anymore. There are (very) few cases when you actually need an empty `catch` block. You know it because there's no other way to handle a very specific situation

Comment: @Jimi , `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'` . `dt.Columns("Total") Nothing` I have an error

Comment: @Jimi ,  `source1.DataSource = dt Dim totalColumn As New DataColumn() totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")  totalColumn.ColumnName = "Total" totalColumn.Expression = "[CIU]*[QTY]"  dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn)  Me.bunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = source1`I made it like it worked but the position in the code is correct